# Load sliding layer after camera bitmap/image save

Tags: java, android

Im Still fresh so go easy.

This is my OnClickListener for my camera

```
buttonClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapture);

    buttonClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            preview.mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);


            }

        }
    );}
```

And this is the code to save to sd card

```
private class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<byte[], Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(byte[]... data) {
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;

        // Write to SD Card
        try {
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/camtest");
            dir.mkdirs();

            String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
            File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);

            outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
            outStream.write(data[0]);
            outStream.flush();
            outStream.close();

            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length + " to " + outFile.getAbsolutePath());

            refreshGallery(outFile);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
        return null;


        }
    }
```

and then i call my sliding layer up

```
 public void buttonClicked(View v){
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnCapture:
                if (!mSlidingLayer.isOpened()) {
                    mSlidingLayer.openLayer(true);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.buttonClose:
                if (mSlidingLayer.isOpened()) {
                    mSlidingLayer.closeLayer(true);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

How do i implement my OnClickListener from my camera with the buttonClicked from my sliding layer in one instance.

I tried combining the two but that gave me the RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap error because the sliding layer was coming into effect before the Save Image Task could complete.

Any help would be great.

Kind regards Sean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger the code to slide your layer in the `onPostExecute()` method of your `AsyncTask`. This method will be called when the task has completed, and will be called on the main thread so you can safely manipulate UI classes.